# questions/{id} API not working as intended for vectorized id

Tags: bug, status-norepro

Show Console > Try it > **Call Method** button on [questions/{id} API page](http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.1/usage/methods/questions-by-ids) is not working properly for vectorized id ie. when I am passing 7282205 it is working fine, but when I am passing- 7282205; 7283777; it is giving error:

```
{
 "error": {
  "code": 404,
  "message": "The server has not found anything matching the Request-URI."
 }
}
```

Can anyone tell me - if there is any problem in API or am I passing wrong parameters ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works fine for me using the following URL:

> http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.1/questions/7282205;7283777

Does that match the URL you are using?

Comment: Thanks, I think I got the problem... I was adding an extra semicolon at the end of semicolon delimited list!